# I don't see .bashrc file in my /home and /etc/skel direcories

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint

I am running linux mint 17.1 rebecca, but I have found it quite different with other distros I am used to, in `/home` and /`etc/skel` there's no `.bashrc` I don't know if i mess up with something or it is by default in this distro so my question specifically, is it okay to have a system without that file or should I create one and how to create it?

When I type

```
 ls -a $HOME /etc/skel
```

I get
[image]

or

```
ls -a $HOME /etc/skel | grep ".bashrc"
```

[image]

Comment: what color scheme is that? looks great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perfectly okay to have a system without that file. Which is why it can't be found on any bare bones system. That file is copied from `/etc/skel` into the new user's home folder upon user creation and it will be in the home folder because of that fact or because someone put it there manually.

The reason you'd want to have a `.bashrc` (or `.bash_profile` or both) is so that during login Bash will execute whatever commands (and custom settings) you desire.

Keep in mind that even Bash itself is optional. While some POSIX-compliant shell has to exist, it needn't be Bash.

Answer (score 3):

In Linux Mint 17, the file is bash.bashrc in the /etc folder.
/etc/bash.bashrc

Comment: That's as may be, but it's not the file that the other person is looking for. (Yours is the system-wide initialisation code; theirs is the personal copy.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also search for files on your system with the '**locate**' command.

Before using the command (for the first time) you will have to populate the **updatedb** database that keeps track of where everything is on your machine (and is what the updatedb command queries). That must be done as a root user.

So, first populate your updatedb database:

```
sudo updatedb
```

Then, run locate to look for something. Eg:

```
locate bash.bashrc
```

Note: You can use wildcards with the locate command. So, for example:

```
locate bash.*
```

Works perfectly